# How to get a vertical gradient background to work in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, css

If you were to get a vertical gradient background starting from white down to some shade of grey, how would you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with CSS, check out [this link](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/).

It uses CSS3 properties in good browsers, and IE's propriety `filter` property when using IE.

#### CSS

```
#gradient {
    background: #FFFFFF; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFFFF), color-stop(100%,#CCCCCC)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CCCCCC',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}
```

*...produces...*

[image: gradient]

Comment: @Sebastian Patane Masuelli Maybe not (in my quick Googling).

Comment: actually, yes: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/

Comment: @Sebastian Patane Masuelli Where does it say it IE6 compatible? I must be blind :P

Comment: @alex: it doesn't specify IE6, but i tested their demo page: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/gradient-box.html  on netrenderer [http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php] for ie6 and it showed the gradient

Comment: @@Sebastian Patane Masuelli That's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

```
background: url('vertical-gradient.jpg') repeat-x #eee
```

I'd recommend repeating your gradient image across the x-axis, then having a solid color that matches the bottom gradient color.  In my example, that would be `#eee`.

The end result is something like this:

```
AAAAAA <- start gradient image
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
DDDDDD
EEEEEE <- end gradient image
EEEEEE <- start solid color until end of document
```

Comment: tip: you should make your image only one pixel wide, it's repeating horizontally, so that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it work in literally all browsers is to use an image.

Comment: Sounds interesting... though I have no idea how to do it, how would you do it?

Comment: ...and even so, the image isn't scale-able.

Comment: Actually, you can get it to [work in all major browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222611/how-to-get-a-vertical-gradient-background-to-work-in-all-browsers/4222645#4222645).