# CSS Gradients with Little Content

Tags: css

When I use gradients, with little content, the gradient repeats, how can I prevent that?

http://jsfiddle.net/mcqpP/1/

I can try using `html { height: 100%; }`, but when my content requires scrolling ... the gradient repeats

http://jsfiddle.net/mcqpP/3/

How can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not render your gradient out as an 1px-wide image and use something like the following:

```
body {  
     background-color: #fff;
     background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
     background-position: center top;
     background-repeat: repeat-x; 
}
```

Setting the background-repeat value will help you control how the background... repeats. In this case it would be rendered as a solid band across the top.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp

Also, using an image should work across all browsers, whereas the moz-gradients could be problematic. The image method above should render very predictable results across all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set percentages on the CSS gradients, not absolute pixels.  And as long as you only care about modern browsers (i.e. you don't care about IE6) then I suggest you stay away from images, the CSS works fine.

I'm pulling my answer from the answer to this question that I wish I could upvote 100 times:
[How to get a vertical gradient background to work in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222611/how-to-get-a-vertical-gradient-background-to-work-in-all-browsers)  That accepted answer has everything you need with full cross browser compatibility.

Here's where I took your example and made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/HJvpf/1/

```
body {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, red 0%, blue 100%);  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 100%, from(red), to(blue)); 
}
```

Oh and in your 2nd jsFiddle link, the reason it was repeating the gradient is because you set height 100% on `html` but the gradient was on `body`.  You move that `height: 100%;` to the `body` and it works fairly well, but as you can see in my solution you don't need to specify height at all.

**Edit:** So you don't want it to repeat, but you also don't want it to take up the entire height.  Just set `repeat-x`.  http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp

```
body {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, red, blue) repeat-x;  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(red), to(blue)) repeat-x; 
}
```

To have the bottom gradient color fill the rest of the space:

```
body {
    background: blue -moz-linear-gradient(top, red, blue) repeat-x;  
    background: blue -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(red), to(blue)) repeat-x; 
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use percentages as it will change the gradient according to the size of content. I guess u get what I mean? It will look different (very different) if you have content of different sizes on the page

Comment: If you don't want the size of the gradient to change, I strongly recommend you use the first approach I suggested, and set the background color as the color of the bottom pixel. This will give you a smooth gradient across the top, and the rest of the element will be filled with solid color matching the bottom pixel. This gives the effect of a seamless gradient fading into a color, and the gradient will not change size. Is this what you are after?

Comment: See the additional information now in my answer above.  Basically you just need to add repeat-x.

Comment: hmm, but without setting a pixel or percentage value for the color stops, I think the gradient will stretch?

Comment: What do you mean by "I think the gradient will stretch?"?  Did you try my solution?

Comment: Pixel values work just fine, but in Webkit you should leave out the `px`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but realised that it made sense and so just accepted the scrolling / repeating gradient. You could set a fixed height, not %, but to ensure that the gradient didn't repeat you would need to set the height as bigger than anybody's screen who wants to view it. And you don't know what resolutions people have. My advice is to just leave it.

Comment: leave it repeating? It looks off don't it? probably I'll set the last color stop to something like 99999px doubt any page will be that long

Comment: Ah, so you actually want the gradient to show for the full height of the object (makes sense now that I have read our question more closely). This may work for you - http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/ (see "Cross-Browser CSS Gradient")

Comment: Remember jiewmeng, if you set the height too large then won't get a great gradient effect.