# CSS Gradients with little content: Fix has problem with Chrome

Tags: css, gradient

I asked a question [CSS Gradients with little content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873150/css-gradients-with-little-content) some time back

I came up with a possible fix http://jsfiddle.net/aruUS/2/

```
html, body { min-height: 100% }
body { 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, blue, red 200px); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 200px, from(blue), to(red));
}
```

only the Firefox part works, it appears webkit only supports percentages for color stops? Anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `px` from `200px`. Pixel values are unitless in Webkit's gradient syntax. I.e.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 200, from(blue), to(red));
```

See the Surfin' Safari blog's [Introducing CSS Gradients](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/):

> A point is a pair of space-separated values. The syntax supports numbers, percentages or the keywords top, bottom, left and right for point values.

*Numbers* don't have a unit, as opposed to *lengths*, which do, [according to the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#values).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
-webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.3, rgb(255,0,0)),
    color-stop(0.47, rgb(255,0,0)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(0,0,254))
);
```

More information for `-webkit-gradient` visit: http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/aruUS/3/

Tool to help you more: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Comment: thanks, but that still uses "relative" values. this doesn't ->  http://jsfiddle.net/aruUS/6/

Comment: @jiewmeng yes. You choose what fits better :)