# SASS Compass Linear Gradients with px color stops & webkit

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

```
@include linear-gradient(color-stops(#e2e2e2, #fff 600px), top);
```

will generate something like

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(0%, #e2e2e2), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
                                                     ^ this is not 600px
```

Also I learnt from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968896/css-gradients-with-little-content-fix-has-problem-with-chrome) that in webkit I should be using something like 600 instead of 600px.

Does Compass not do that?

Also I need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat` else the gradient will repeat in webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 having the same issue.  Frustratingly, [this compass example page](http://compass-style.org/docs/examples/compass/css3/gradient/) shows gradients working fine in WebKit. Maybe it's a version issue?  I'm about to try downgrading to an earlier version and see if that helps.

---

**EDIT**

Looks like the webkit color stops have been fixed in head. Install the latest version (0.11.beta.2 as of this writing) and **make sure you restart your server** (unlike we did the first time) and you'll find that webkit color stops work properly.