# How to change the background-color when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, background

I have the code for changing the background-color when the user scrolls down, but i need the page to smoothly change the background twice (ex. grey @ paragraph 1, yellow @ paragraph 2, and red @ paragraph 3). Does anyone know how to do this?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var alpha = Math.min(0.5 + 0.4 * $(this).scrollTop() / 3000, 0.9);
        var channel = Math.round(alpha * 255);
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + channel + ',' + channel + ',' + channel + ')');
    });
});
```

Result:

[www.web-app.be/op](http://www.web-app.be/op/)

Comment: What do you mean by changing the background "twice"?

Comment: Can you manipulate this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222611/how-to-get-a-vertical-gradient-background-to-work-in-all-browsers - If I change #FFFFF to #F00 I get a red to grey gradient

Comment: see www.web-app.be/op/
The color changes when you scroll down, from grey to white, I need it to change to a third color when you scroll to paragraph 3.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start with this?

[How to get a vertical gradient background to work in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222611/how-to-get-a-vertical-gradient-background-to-work-in-all-browsers)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Scroll changes bg</title>
<style>
#gradient1 {
    background: #FFFFFF; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F00 0%, #CCCCCC 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFFFF), color-stop(100%,#CCCCCC)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CCCCCC',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}
#gradient2 {
    background: #FFFFFF; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF0 0%, #CCCCCC 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFFFF), color-stop(100%,#CCCCCC)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CCCCCC',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var alpha = Math.min(0.5 + 0.4 * $(this).scrollTop() / 3000, 0.9);
        var channel = Math.round(alpha * 255);
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + channel + ',' + channel + ',' + channel + ')');
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="gradient1<li></li>">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
<div id="gradient2">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```